# Redirect to new page when user select from a dropdown list in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I created an asp.net web application (VB) with a dropdownlist that have lists of url to pages on the server.  I am new to asp and VB. I have research different forums for solution and decided to ask for a specific solution to my problem.

Break down.
- I have a fully built page
- this page gets archive every two hrs to an archive folder(using a vbs)
- An XML file is generated with the file name and url (using a VBS)
- XMl is the datasource for the DDL.

What I want to accomplish is, when the user click an item from the DDL, they should be  directed to that page.

After follow some of the suggestion from other forum and this one, nothing seems to work.

Once we dive into this, we will get some better understanding of any confusion.

- The code-behind is VB, so i will prefered that language.

**ASPX Page**

```
enter code here

<%@ Page Title="Home" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"     AutoEventWireup="false"CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Status._Default" %>     <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content><asp:Content ID="BodyContent"runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"></asp:Content>


<asp:XmlDataSource ID="statsXML" 
    runat="server" DataFile="~/Archive/Stats.xml" 
    XPath="Elements/Element" /> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="statsXML"
     DataTextField="Name" 
     DataValueField="Value" 
     AutoPostBack="True" 
     CssClass="rightCol"  />
<br />
<p>

    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <asp:TableRow BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="12">
            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="Text here" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="0"
                ForeColor="White" BackColor="#006699"></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="12">
            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="Text here" BorderStyle="Solid"
                BorderWidth="0" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#006699"></asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <br />
</p>
<asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" GridLines="both" Width="100%" BorderColor="Black">
    <asp:TableRow BorderWidth="1" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Size="12" BorderColor="Black">
        <asp:TableCell Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="Enviroment" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"
            ForeColor="White" BackColor="#006699" BorderColor="Black"></asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Text="State" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="1" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#006699" BorderColor="Black"></asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>`
```

**Code-Behind**

```
Public Class webform
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        'End If
        'If Page.IsPostBack Then
        '    ' Response.Redirect(Me.DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
        ' End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                                     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged    

        Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: use `response.redirect("url")` in the codebehind..if you dont know where to put the code, go to the designer view and double click on your dropdownlist and put the `response.redirect("url")` in the `sub` that appears to you

Comment: asp.net mvc? webforms?

Comment: @shahkalpesh web application is always webforms right?

Comment: I am trying to paste my code here but I am new tothis forum. I did try that and its not working

Comment: @thunderbird: Can you please explain to me, why will it be webforms always?

Comment: No, MVC and Webforms are two different things.  An ASP.net Web Application could be either.

Comment: @shahkalpesh my bad i read it as empty web application

Comment: @SteveCode Have you written any code yet?  If so, can you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is to first set `AutoPostback` to `True` on your `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDownlist" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" />
```

After that you should be able to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the `DropDownList` in your code-behind

```
Protected Sub myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged

   ' Lookup the selected item and redirect here
   ' (This assumes that you've bound your URL to redirect to the value of the item,
   ' and not the display text.  Use SelectedItem.Text if the URL is being displayed
   Response.Redirect(myDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 Public Class WebForm1
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: what does your text and value fields actually contain?..put this piece of code in the same 'Sub' `msgbox(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+":"+DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text+" Selected")` and check if your name and value fields are correctly assigned and put it before you redirect.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to explain and I hit the enter button. Text contain the text that diplay in the DDL window. Value contain the URL. not visible to user

Comment: @SteveCode your code is correct as far as i can tell..you should know that page_load sub will be executed before the event handler.

Comment: path cannot be found.. But when I use 
>Response.Redirect(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value), no error message. the only problem is, clicking an item in the DDL does not take you to the desire page.

Comment: @Mike C - clicking an item in the DDL does not take you to the desire page. The contents on the default.aspx page is what showing.

Comment: can you directly open the redirected page by entering the Value of the DDL's selected item in the browser's Url field?

Comment: Yes, typing the url in the browser takes me to the page

Comment: btw is your event handler called on the ddl's index being changed?also make sure `enableviewstate` is not set to false.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the selectedindexchanged handler?

Comment: @Mike and Thunderbird, Des this mean anything to you?
This is from source code view from IE

>     <select name="ctl00$MainContent$DropDownList1" >onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00 >$MainContent$DropDownList1\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" >id="MainContent_DropDownList1" class="rightCol2">

Comment: This onchange="javascript:setTimeout is doing something that relate to the page returning to the oringinal page after selecting from the DDL.

Comment: @SteveCode it looks like the postback code is there, so it theoretically should fire.  Sometimes there are things that can interfere with the javascript though.  Do you see any errors in your JS log?  Can you place a breakpoint in your codebehind to see if perhaps the event is posting back?

Comment: @SteveCode can you post your entire aspx and aspx.vb code? including the page directive.

Comment: Sorry gentlemen i got caught up with something. i have edited the aspx section. the code-behing is the same.

Comment: @SteveCode put all your aspx code in the body content place holder...you cant put any code outside the contentplaceholder.

Comment: it is in the contentplaceholder, this site is not showing it. I am having a lil problem inputing code to this site that's why.

Comment: @SteveCode you gotta debug it. Put little messages in your code and your event handler stating what is currently going on(use `msgbox`). Instead of redirecting using the drop down value field redirect using an absolute value so make sure redirection from inside the event handler is working..if nothing works start over again.